# ER Diagram sample- what is the relationship?

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, diagram

Here is a sample question that we have to build the ER Diagram/relationship for... I am struggling as to what the relationship is!

All computers at company have serial numbers. In addition they have purchase date, manufacturer and OS version. Some computers are servers which have the above columns plus a static IP address and server admin. The computers that are non servers are called workstations. They are in offices with a designated room number.

Help please :)

Answer (score 1):

To keep your database fully normalized, you'll want to use 1:0..1 relationships:

```
CREATE TABLE computer {
  serial_number varchar,
  purchase_date date,
  manufacturer varchar,
  os_version varchar,
  computer_type varchar(1),  'server or workstation
  PRIMARY KEY (serial_number)
}

CREATE TABLE computer_server {
  serial_number varchar,
  static_ip varchar,
  admin varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (serial_number),
  CONSTRAINT fk_computer_server FOREIGN KEY (serial_number) REFERENCES computer(serial_number)
}

CREATE TABLE computer_workstation {
  serial_number varchar,
  room_number int,
  PRIMARY KEY (serial_number),
  CONSTRAINT fk_computer_workstation FOREIGN KEY (serial_number) REFERENCES computer(serial_number)
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I totally forgot about the normalization relationship, doh lol

Comment: What is a "normalization relationship"? The computer/server/workstation looks more like a class hierarchy (server and workstation are subclasses of computer) more than they look like relationships between different entities. (i.e. look at what "uniquely identifies" a computer, and what "uniquely identifies" a server. Might these really be the same thing?) The "table per subclass" is one possible implementation, but there are other implementations that might be better suited, such as the table for the superclass, and a discriminator column for the subclasses.

Comment: Database normalization (or normalisation) is the process of organizing the columns (attributes) and tables (relations) of a relational database to minimize data redundancy.... much like a class hierarchy.

Third normal form (3NF) is usually the ideal solution:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Comment: Please upvote if this was the correct answer! thanks

Comment: The correct answer here is `subtyping`.  Server and Workstation are subtypes of Computer, Computer is the supertype.  OO classes are best used to model state machines with encapsulated data, not to model data itself, since objects support only binary directed relationships and fixed access paths.  Also, 3NF is certainly not the ideal solution, it's subject to a number of data anomalies.  It's only popular because of ER and because multivalued dependencies are hare to understand.

Answer (score 0):

First, figure out what the "entities" are.

An entity is a person, place, thing, concept or event that 1) can be uniquely identified 2) is important to the business, and 3) we want to store information about.

Take the spec, and pull out anything that looks like it might be an entity. These may not all be entities, but they are candidates for us to consider in developing a model.

- computer
- company
- serial number
- purchase  (event)
- manufacturer
- OS version
- server
- static IP address (the "network" may also be an entity)
- server admin (person)
- workstation
- office

Once we have a list of candidate entities, we ask appropriate questions to find out the relationships between them.

Let's start with "office" and "workstation".  Is there a relationship there? Let's throw some words at it... we may not know the right words, but we can take a stab at it. For lack of something better, let's try...

- A workstation can "be in" an office.
- An office may "have" a workstation.

Now, we need to ask some appropriate questions, to figure out the cardinality of the relationship. Is it one to one, one to many, zero-or-one to many, etc. The questions we ask would typically be of the form:

- Can an office have more than one workstation?
- Can a worktation "be in" more than one office?
- Can an office have zero workstations?
- Can a workstation not "be in" an office?

Based on the answers to those questions, we determine whether the relationship is required... for example whether a workstation MUST be in an office. Is that mandatory or optional in our model?

(Ignoring modeling of temporal data, modeling the state at a single point in time, we will likely determine that:

- a workstation can "be in" one-or-zero office
- an office can "have" zero, one, or more workstation

This is an example of a one-to-many relationship, where the relationship is optional.

---

Some of our candidate entities will turn out not to be entities in our model. For example, perhaps the "manufacturer" of a computer is not important to the business, or maybe we don't need to store any information to store about a "purchase" event.

---

The relationship between "server" and "server admin"...

- Can a "server" be administered by more than one "server admin"?
- Can a "server admin" (person) administer more than one "server?
- Can a "server admin" (person) administer zero servers?
- Can a "server" be administered by zero administrators?

This will will likely turn out to be a many-to-many relationship in our model. (We'll likely introduce an additional "administrates" table to resolve the many-to-many relationship, where the new "administrates" relationship table will have foreign key relationships to both "server" and "server admin".

Comment: First, figure out the predicates that you need to record.  The roles in the predicates will prescribe the entity sets.